# Make the javascript don't run in specific countries

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript redirect script. which redirects when the country is US.

```
<script>
function determineCountry(data){
   switch(data.address.country_code){
      case "US" :
         document.location.href = "http://xxxxxxxx.biz/theme.php";
      break;
   }    
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=determineCountry"></script>
```

Now what i want is the reverse of this. like don't run the script when the country is US.

thanks in advance

Comment: This a redirect, not running a script.  So, are you just trying to NOT redirect when the country is US?

Comment: `case "US": return;`?

Comment: Just don't add the country case to the switch? This will be easily by-passed by someone who knows how to open dev-tools though, just a fyi.

Comment: `case "US": return;` not working

Comment: @jite you meant add all the country names? isn't there any alternative. like from a programmers pov. also i think this redirect script acts when the page runs. so how someone can stop the redirect that quicky

Comment: No, i mean that you only add the countries that are supposed to be redirected, the rest you leave out, then nothing will happen. Anything that is happening client-side is possible to manipulate by a client. A redirect via js, even if its as soon as the page loads, can be stopped. For example by using a no-script plugin or similar. Client-side is always compromised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do a `break` if the country is 'US'. change `document.location.href` in the `default` `switch` section.

```
function determineCountry(data){
   switch(data.address.country_code){
      case "US" :
         break;
      default:
         document.location.href = "http://xxxxxxxx.biz/theme.php";
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A case in a switch will happen if the condition is true. That is, in your case, if `data.address.country_code == "US"` the case will be fired.

If no case is found that fulfills the condition, the default case will be used (if one is set).
If you wish to redirect a few countries but not all, you add those countries to the switch, that is, the countries that are supposed to be redirected, else you just leave them out.

```
function determineCountry(data){
  switch(data.address.country_code){
  case "SE" :
     document.location.href = "http://xxxxxxxx.biz/theme.php"; 
     break;
   }    
}

determineCountry('SE'); // Will redirect.
determineCountry('US'); // Will not redirect.
determineCountry('CZ'); // Will not redirect.
```

You could also add all the countries that you want to redirect to a list, and do this with a single if:

```
var codesToRedirectOn = ['SE', 'IT'];
function redirectIfCountry(code) {
  if(codesToRedirectOn.indexOf(code) !== -1) {
    // Redirect.
  }
  // Don't redirect (i.e., do nothing). 
}
```

---

An important thing to note though, when doing logic that is on the client side, is that the client side code is always in the hands of the client. A client can easily by-pass the redirection code if they wish.
If you want it more secure, the redirect should be done server-side before the page is even loaded.

Comment: Thanks. also thanks for the client side info. but unfortunately my cms doesn't support serverside